# Node-Red Dashboard: Determine width and height of a group

Tags: javascript, dashboard, node-red

In a NR dashboard I'm trying to determine the width and heigth of a widget group:

```
var groupWidth = document.getElementById('Home_Test2_cards').offsetWidth;
var groupHeight = document.getElementById('Home_Test2_cards').offsetHeight;
```

It works for `groupWidth` but not for `groupHeight`. I found some references that a div will not return its height when set to invisible but this is not the case here. Is there any way to determine the height?

Using jQuery:

Calling `var groupHeight = $('#Home_Test2_cards').height();` works but still only returns 0.

Edit:

[Browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Zq0.png)

Dashboard Template content:

```
<script>
(function(scope) {
  scope.$watch('msg.payload', function(data) {
    if (data !== undefined) {
      imageObj.src=data;
    }
  });
}(scope));

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var groupWidth = document.getElementById('Home_Test2_cards').offsetWidth;
//var groupHeight = document.getElementById('Home_Test2_cards').offsetHeigth;
var groupHeight = $('#Home_Test2_cards').height();

console.log('Width:' + groupWidth);
console.log('Height:' + groupHeight);

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload= function() {
  var wRatio = groupWidth / imageObj.width;
  var hRatio = groupHeight / imageObj.height;
  var ratio = Math.min(wRatio, hRatio);
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, imageObj.width*ratio, imageObj.height*ratio);
};
</script> 

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Based on the screenshot above I would expect the height to be 351.

Answer (score 0):

The node-red Dashboard includes the JQuery library, so you should be able to use:

```
var groupWidth = $('#Home_Test2_cards').width;
var groupHeight = $('#Home_Test2_cards').height;
```

Comment: Hmm, it works for the `<div>` i tested in my dashboard... so it must be dependent on the _contents_ of the div element. Could you update the question with a snippet of the div and its contents, so we could test it?

Comment: Which browser are you using? And have you checked any other browsers? Instead of your code, I was asking for the div's outer html _content_ so I can build the same structure and try it locally...

Comment: FF or Chrome gives the same result.

Comment: Regarding the outer html content, I do not understand your question. This is simply a Node Red dashboard UI template (not html template) with the content pasted above. This template node automatically creates all the stuff as shown in the OP screenshot and all I add is the canvas to place the image. See this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/7EDprcR.png)

Comment: Well since I don't have the incoming msg data that is being sent to the dashboard, I would need to see the actual html that is rendered -- in the dev console (F12) can you find/copy the *html* of the `<div>` element for the group?

Comment: Please see this [paste](https://pastebin.com/YGxkWsfc). The relevant html begins in line 323 and I would like to have the width and height returned as stated in line 330.
Basically this should be independent of the msg.payload send to the canvas as it just represents a 6x6 grid UI dashboard template.

Comment: I think I see the problem -- are you trying to get the height of a div with no content?

Comment: The NR Dashboard UI creates the empty div with `width: 351px; height: 351px;`. I place the canvas there ´<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>`, so it should not longer be empty and I would like to have the 351 / 351 returned.